# Will make-kpkg compile modules too?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I want to build latest (4.7.4) kernel with make-kpkg. Also I want to make it as modular as possible. Will it compile modules too or should I run 'make modules' before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will compile modules. Please refer to http://man.he.net/man1/make-kpkg .

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will.
When the process finalized its work, then you'll be seen two files, "kernel-image" and "kernel-headers".